# sscanf not setting value of an int

Tags: c

I am passing a number int into this method but it is not storing the int in the method that calls the intchange method. Any pointers?

```
int intchange(const char *prompt, int number){
  char buffer[LINESIZE];

  while(1){
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if(!fgets(buffer,LINESIZE, stdin)){
      clearerr(stdin);
      return 0;
    }
   if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number) == 1){
     /*exit variable */
   if(number== -1)
      return 0;
   else if (number<= 110 && number>= 0)
      return 1;
       }
     }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Any pointers?" ...  Funny you should mention it.

Comment: What is that version of `gets()`?

Comment: i retyped it from my second screen which is running linux and has no internet... its supposed to be fgets(). Thanks for helping a beginner.

Comment: really... I got downvoted for asking a question after I couldn't find the answer through researching... That is not helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the change to be visible to the caller you need to pass the *address* of the `int` into `intchange()`. Otherwise a copy of the `int` provided by the caller is being changed, not the `int` the caller provided as C passes by value:

```
int intchange(const char* prompt, int* number)
{
    /* snip */
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", number) == 1){ /* Removed address of operator. */

        if(*number == -1)                  /* Dereference to query int value. */
        /* snip */
    }
}
```

Invoked:

```
int i;
if (intchange("14", &i))
{
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
}
```

See [Does C even have ``pass by reference''?](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passbyref.html).

Comment: so intchange(prompt, *number)?

Comment: so I cant then compare the pointer to an int like

    if(number== -1)
          return 0;
       else if (number<= 110 && number>= 0)
          return 1;

Comment: @user1743622, yes you can by dereferencing it: `(if *number == -1)`

Comment: ahhh ok.. I need to work on pointers I think. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

use pointer for the input parameter number:

```
int intchange(const char *prompt, int *number){

if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", number) == 1){

if(*number== -1)
      return 0;
   else if (*number<= 110 && *number>= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an argument into a function, you're passing a copy of it.  So in your case, the `int number` argument is just a copy of the int, which gets assigned to in your function, and then disappears when the function returns.

The solution is something like this:

```
int intchange(const char *prompt, int* pNumber) {
  char buffer[LINESIZE];
  while (1) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if (!gets(buffer,LINESIZE, stdin)) {
      clearerr(stdin);
      return 0;
    }
    int number;
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number) == 1) {
      /*exit variable */
      *pNumber = number;
      if(number== -1)
        return 0;
      else if (number<= 110 && number>= 0)
        return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, you're passing in the *address* of an `int` (in the argument `pNumber`), which can be modified through the pointer.  You would then call it like so:

```
int n;
intchange("prompt", &n);
```

and then `n` would have the value input.  See also: http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/revisit.html